# Not able to find file using ssh on another server using python pexpect on linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, terminal, pexpect

I created the simple python script using pexpect, created one spwan process using

```
 CurrentCommand = "ssh " + serverRootUserName + "@" + serverHostName
 child = pexpect.spawn(CurrentCommand)
```

Now I am running some command like ls-a or "find /opt/license/  -name '*.xml'"
 using code

```
 child.run(mycommand)
```

it works fine if running from Pycharm  but if running from terminal it is not working it is not able to find any file, I think it is looking into my local system.

Can anyone suggest me something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, have a look at the paramiko library (or fabric, which uses it, but has a specific purpose), as this is a python interface to ssh. It might make your code a bit better and more resilient against bugs or attacks.

However, I think the issue comes from your use of `run`.

> This function runs the given command; waits for it to finish; then returns all output as a string. STDERR is included in output. If the full path to the command is not given then the path is searched.

What you should look at is 'expect'. I.e. your spawn with `spawn` then you should use `expect` to wait for that to get to an appropiate point (such as connected, terminal ready after motd pushed etc (because ouy might have to put a username and password in etc).

Then you want to run `sendline` to send a line to the program. See the example:

http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Hope that helps, and seriously, have a look at paramiko ;)

Comment: I used this already but it is not working child.sendline('mycommand') followed by 
child.expect('prompt:')

Comment: You should expect *then* send line: basically you have to wait for the ssh to connect before you are trying to push more data at it. I am suprised that the ssh would not ask for a username and password (unless you are using ssh keys, but you would be better to use the -i argument to specify your key on the original ssh connection. Run does *not* attach to the process that you started though - its more for running scripts.

Comment: i havn't write the full code here i ran the command child = pexpect.spawn(CurrentCommand) and provided the password , So i have the child object now which is the SSH to another server now if I am running from unix terminal  child.sendline(find /opt/license/ -name '*.xml') followed by child.expect('prompt:')  it is not displaying the data, But running from Pycharm is working, It looks like it is looking into my local server from where I ran the python script file i.e. user@hostname.com mypyhton.py